# Updating TextBox Inner Text without refreshing the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing a platform with some friends as a project for a university subject. We're trying to make an IRC using ASP.NET but we're facing a problem right now.

We have this textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLog" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

And then we have in the code-behind a function who checks if you're still connected to our server, and if you are it reads the stream that is coming from him and append it to the TextBox.

```
txtLog.Text += string.Format(strReceptor.ReadLine() + "\r\n");
```

The thing is, the property Text of this TextBox is updated but in the page it is not displayed. How can we update the Text inside the TextBox on the webpage without refreshing the page? We don't want to refresh the page because if we do we lose the connection to the server.

We know that we can use JavaScript to update it but we weren't sucessful doing it. We tried a function but it was only called once.

The function who updates the Text property it's inside a cycle which is running on a new Thread, so that it keeps checking if something comes out of the server, and if it does append it to the TextBox.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you declare a new textbox in server side with the same name? normally it will just work

Comment: Try AJAX call? something like, check the server every minute (configurable) then update the textbox.

Comment: @excaliburCayote unfortunately it isn't working.

Comment: @Chris We haven't. Can you give me a code example on how to do it, if it's not asking too much? Thanks

Comment: Probably you can start from here http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: @Chris No errors but, the textbox is still not being updated, at least on the page because the property is updated without problems.

Comment: @DiogoMartinho i think i found your issue, 
Did you enclose page load code in IsPostBack? If not, please add validation for postback in page load function, code something like this, 
`if (!base.IsPostBack)`

Comment: If it isn't postback what should it do? And, should I put it on Page_Load or on OnLoad?

Comment: You must use update panel.

Comment: @hdkhardik Can I have a snippet if it's not asking too much? Thanks

Comment: @DiogoMartinho can you please share the code which get's data back from stream ? may I see that event ?

Comment: @hdkhardik here you go sir: http://pastebin.com/jfApnC8K. This is just the part where it gets the data and writes it to the TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this with ajax:

```
var addedStr = '';
var oldValue = $('#' + <%=txtLog.ClientID%>).val();
$('#' + <%=txtLog.ClientID%>).val(oldValue + addedStr);
```

Comment: `addedStr` is the string you want to add.

Comment: but the string is dynamic, it keeps fetching from the stream until there is data to fetch or the connection is closed. I've tried to use it, here is the snippet I've been using but nothing happened. https://jsfiddle.net/51bwdcxx/

Comment: You didn't want to refresh the page, so you uesd ajax, right?

Comment: You can get `addedStr` via ajax method.

Answer (score 1):

I will post here the solution that we've followed to help someone who might catch up this post later and is currently facing the same problem that we did.

ASPX page code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Timer ID="UpdateTimer" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="UpdateTimer_Tick" Enabled="True"></asp:Timer>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="TimedPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateTimer" EventName="Tick" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
    // Content to be updated each 1000ms
</ContentTemplate>
```

Relevant properties of Timer:

- Interval: Represents the time in milisseconds that this content will
  be updated
- OnTick: Method on code behind which will be executed each
  A milisseconds

Code behind:

```
protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code to be executed with the timer is triggered
}
```

As simple as this. Any problem, please answer I can try to solve it!
Good luck!